# Why running rake assets:precompile doesn't follow the hierarchy in app/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have been developing rails applications for a while and one thing that I am still wondering is why when we run

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

The complied assets are not placed in accordance with the directory structure or hierarchy in the app/assets. For example, suppose this is my directory structure in app/assets

```
/assets
    /images
        /products
    /javascripts
        example.coffee
        application.js
    /stylesheets
        example.scss
        application.css
```

Once these files get complied, the result of the task is something like following

```
/public
    /assets
        /products
    example-abffe803d3849a1374ec27fc1799e58113ec962a39922467623a40f40c3fd5c0.css
    example-abffe803d3849a1374ec27fc1799e58113ec9623d3849a1374ec2f40c3fd5c0.js
```

It doesn't follow the hierarchy of the app/assets directory when complied.  Everything except products folder in app/assets/images is placed in the public/assets/ folder. In fact, It should be something like the following.

```
/public
    /assets
        /images
            /products
        /javascripts
            example-abffe803d3849a1374ec27fc1799e58113ec9623d3849a1374ec2f40c3fd5c0.js
        /stylesheets
            example-abffe803d3849a1374ec27fc1799e58113ec962a39922467623a40f40c3fd5c0.css
```

Is there any way to handle the assets:precompile operation to follow the folder structure defined in app/assets?

Comment: what problem is this differing folder structure causing?

Comment: It is difficult to manage the files because there are hundred of them in main /public/assets folder

Comment: why do you need to manage them after they have been compiled?

Comment: I can't run rake on the production server so I have to upload the complied files to the server. Some of them can't be loaded. Not sure what causes these errors

Comment: what do you mean by not loaded, is it like firebug shows errors like file not found. Any file hierarchy can be maintained in application.js or application.css files.